# Group By gives me the oldest results from the database

Tags: mysql

I' am currently using the following SQL to get the latest message from the Database. The following SQL gives me the oldest message in the database. I' am Grouping By **message_replay_id** because this is the common column in the database and I' am also using it for the reference.

**Database Structure and Result from the Query**

[image]

**This is all the records without using the Query**
[image]

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE message_from = '1' || message_to = '1'
GROUP BY message_replay_id 
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

As you can see, the message_id are

> 11, 7, 5, 1 (Oldest ID's)

but infact the latest ID's are

> 13, 7, 6, 20

My Question again is what am I doing wrong that I' am not able to get the Latest Results from the Database.

Comment: Why do you group by `message_replay_id`?

Comment: I' am Grouping By `message_replay_id` because this is the common column in the database and I' am also using it for the reference.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to do. Can you add example data of the table?

Comment: Unlike other DBMS, MySQL won't warn by default when you run an incomplete grouped by query. Instead, it'll just pick an arbitrary (not even random) value whenever it needs to discard all rows but one.

Comment: Are you sure that the latest id's are 13,7,6,20 and not 13,**10**,6,20?

Comment: Which message_id, message_from and message_to is returned for each message_replay_id is arbitary.

Comment: @Kickstart - Please see my post under "Database Structure and Result from the Query"

Comment: Yes, but NOTHING in your query defines that the latest records are to be returned. Whether it returns the latest or oldest record is not defined. MySQL is free to return whichever one is most convenient to it.

Comment: See this to understand the quirks for MySQL's "loose" group by handling: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest result you need match up the latest row.

The easiest way is using a sub query to get the latest row for each message_replay_id, and then join that back against messages to get the rest of the details.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM messages a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT message_replay_id, MAX(message_id) AS latest_message
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_from = '1' || message_to = '1'
    GROUP BY message_replay_id 
) b
ON a.message_replay_id = b.message_replay_id
AND a.message_id = b.latest_message
ORDER BY a.message_id DESC
```